# Symmetric power of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$, and $S^kX$ be the $k^{th}$ symmetric power of $X$. Assume $X$ is an oriented manifolds, does it induce an orientation on $S^kX$? and if it does how?

Comment: Have you thought about what happens when $n$ is even? At any rate, you should indicate what you've tried when you post your question and say where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No, $S^{2}(S^1)$ is a Mobius band (with boundary).

One way to see this is to see the torus as a standard indentification space of the square. Then a triangle will be a fundamental domain of the involution switching the factors. Now, see how the boundary of the triangle is identified, it is a Mobius band.

Comment: Great example. What about the case that $n$ is even?

Comment: In the case when $n$ is even the symmetric product is an orientable orbifold, and when the quotient turns out to be a manifold it is an orientable manifold. This because for any chart $U \subset X$ the action of $S_{n}$ on $U \times \ldots \times U$ preserves the natural orientation. This gives orientable orbifold charts on the quotient.

Comment: Yes, the transpositions are orientation-preserving if and only if $n$ is even. (Your last remark is confusing, since $\dim X = n$ in the OP.)

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right.  Mometarily confused myself.